# powerquery: extra digits added to number when importing table

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, m

Glad to ask a question here again after more than 10 years (last one was about BASH scripting, now as I'm in corporate, guess what... it's about excel ;) )

here it's my question/issue:
I am importing data with powerquery for further analysis

I have discovered is that the values imported contains extradigits not present in the original table.

I have googled for this problem but I have not been able to find an explanation nor a solution (  a similar issue is [this one](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Power-Query/Inaccurate-Decimal-Numbers/m-p/1706314/highlight/true#M51874)  this one , more than one year old, but with no feedback from Microsoft )

[image: screenshot source + powerquery]

(columns are formatted as text in the screenshot but  the issue is still present even if formatted as number)

The  workaround I am using now, but I am not happy with that is the following:

1. I "increased decimal" to make sure all my digits are captured (in my source the entries do not have all the same significant digits),
2. saved as csv
3. imported impacted columns as number
4. convert columns as text (for future text match

I am really annoyed by this unwanted and unpredictable behaviour of excel.
I see a serious issue of data integrity, if we cannot rely on the powerquery/powerbi platform to maintain accurate queries, I wonder why would be use it

adding another screenshot to clarify that changing the source format to text does not solve the problem
[image]

another screenshot added following @David Bacci comments:

[image]

I think I wrongfully assumed my data was stored as text in the source, can you confirm?

Comment: also the workaround is not working as it is supposed to do, in some cases the extrazeros are kept when converting it to text, in some cases not...

Comment: after forcing the columns in the source as text as suggested [here](https://superuser.com/a/1648558/1751788) the issue was resolved.

Answer (score 2):

If you are exporting and importing as text, then this will not happen. If  you convert to number, you will lose precision. From the docs (my bold):

> Represents a 64-bit (eight-byte) floating-point number. It's the most
> common number type, and corresponds to numbers as you usually think of
> them. Although designed to handle numbers with fractional values, it
> also handles whole numbers. The Decimal Number type can handle
> negative values from –1.79E +308 through –2.23E –308, 0, and positive
> values from 2.23E –308 through 1.79E + 308. For example, numbers like
> 34, 34.01, and 34.000367063 are valid decimal numbers. **The largest
> precision that can be represented in a Decimal Number type is 15
> digits long.** The decimal separator can occur anywhere in the number.
> The Decimal Number type corresponds to how Excel stores its numbers.
> **Note that a binary floating-point number can't represent all numbers
> within its supported range with 100% accuracy. Thus, minor differences
> in precision might occur when representing certain decimal numbers.**

BTW, you should probably accept some of the good answers from your previous questions from 10 years ago.

Comment: Hello David
as you can see in my screenshot, I am not losing precisions or digits. I am getting NEW extra digits when importing in powerquery, that are NOT present in the original data. see the extra zeros that I added to make sure of that

Comment: That is losing precision. The extra zeroes are part of the precision and causing the problem.

Comment: please re-read my question and the screenshot

Comment: I have. I think you need to do a bit more research on how computers store floating point numbers. The following is a good starter. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PZRI1IfStY0

Comment: If you need long precision on decimals, Excel is not your friend. David shows the way